# Predicate with OR in CloudKit iOS 9

Tags: ios, predicate, cloudkit

I just would need to know how to work out a CKQuery with OR in the predicate. I know OR is not supported in a predicate with CloudKit. Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Well I'm not using `CKQuery`, however, if there are an `AND` and `NOT` keywords, then `OR` could be equal to `NOT(NOT(X) AND NOT(Y))`

Comment: thanks for your reply, so how would you rewrite a predicate like this: NSPredicate(format: "aRecord = %@ OR aRecord = %@", recordA, recordB)?

Comment: I was wrong, checking the docs: "The NOT compound operator is not supported in the following cases:  You cannot use it to negate an AND compound predicate. ..." so this solution will not work.

Comment: yep, i've just noticed that too. hopefully somebody will find an alternative to still build an OR predicate

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found out a solution for what I needed by using Reference List field.

```
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"ALL %@ IN inboxReferences", [CKReference(record: currentUserRecord, action: .None) ,CKReference(record: otherUserRecord, action: .None)])
```

In this way the query I perform searches for all the References stored into an **Inbox** Record Type where I have an "*inboxReferences*" field, then I call each reference in this way:

```
let inboxRef = inboxClass["inboxReferences] as! NSArray
let senderRef = inboxRef[0] as! CKReference
let receiverRef = inboxRef[1] as! CKReference
```